# Need to fetch data from prometheus using c#

Tags: c#, prometheus

need to fetch data from prometheus for a custom query.Able to get the data from by using the entire metrics.
automation_results{testCase="abc"} is the query am looking at,needs to return the results stored in prometheus that has metric name as 'automation_results' and testCase as 'abc'.need to pass the query to prometheus,am using C#,couldnt find any implementation of prometheusClient which would take in the custom query and return the results.

Comment: Where in your code do you have the problem? Do you get an error message?

Comment: i dont have an implementation for fetching custom query from prometheus in prometheus client ,will be looking at some implementation in nuget which i can use.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get the implementation done as suggested by sandersaares using the https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/
in github
https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net/issues/162